# PHP query parsing couchdb

Tags: php, couchdb

I am new to php so, need any help for this issue

I tried to run query

```
localhost/ls-test/_design/app-views/_view/timestamp-measurement?descending=true&include_docs=true
```

and get json return something like this format:

```
{"total_rows":441740,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"123","key":[2013,2],"value":["1","PowerConsumption","0.0"],"doc":{"_id":"5446691910660799","SourceType":"SENSOR","SourceId":"4294403072","Property":"PowerConsumption","value":"0.0","}},
{"id":"124","key":[2013,2],"value":["228224","Motion","false"],"doc":{"_id":"5446688472521031","SourceType":"SENSOR","SourceId":"228224","Property":"Motion","value":"false","timestamp":"2013-02-12 17:06:06.768"}}
...]}
```

so, how do I further query it in PHP that my result only displayed based on specific value e.g only list of documents with SourceId:228224

Comment: I do not want to make a new view in couchdb since my couchdb database contains hundred thousands of documents already and adding more view only burden the server. so I would rather use php syntax to manipulate one view.

Comment: You'd rather get back more than 440 thousand rows than create a new view? That is burdening the server, to say the least. Creating a new view is the right way to go for your search given what you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would json_decode in PHP then work with your associative array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php